# Bool true или false

Tags: c++, c, if, условия

Мне нужно сделать `bool`, который будет возвращать `true`, если `(1 + (rand() % 101)) <= 50`, в противном случае возвращать `false`.

Хочу сделать так, чтобы если `bool == true`, то выполнять функцию, если нет — не выполнять.

Через `if (mybool == true)` не выходило.

Comment: bool что?  функцию? в чем проблема, не очень понятно, уже все написано

Answer (score 1):

Но в чем проблема?

```
if ((1 + (rand() % 101)) <= 50) call_function();
```

Comment: У меня примерно так выглядит код
void CSetup::Run()
{
 ...
 if (Settings::Myfunc)
{
//тут код выполнения
}
...
}

Тобишь мне по логике надо сделать так?
 if (Settings::Myfunc && ((1 + (rand() % 101)) <= 50))
{
...
}

Comment: сработает такое?